# input of (do you want to do it again) not working

Tags: python

*im trying to do url shortener tool , but im facing a problem that when the link is done
and the tool will ask the user if he want to do it again*

*so the problem here that if user inputed n the tool won't exit*

**Code :**

```
 again = input(f"{r}[?]{b}Do you want to short another link (y/n) ==> ")
 if again == 'y'or'Y':
     os.system('cls')
     logo()
     link = input(f"{r}[/]{b}Enter the link (google.com) --> ")
 elif again == 'n'or'N':
     print(f"{r}[-]{b}Thanks for using the tool !")
     exit()
 else:
     print(f"{r}[!]{b}Not a valid option")
```

**what is the error here please help me**

Comment: `if again == 'y'or'Y'` That is not the right way to check a variable or multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not evaluating what you think you're evaluating.

```
if again == 'y' or 'Y':
```

is not the same as

```
if again == 'y' or again == 'Y':
```

in your terminal, try

```
if "Y":
    print(True)
```

you'll see that it evaluates to True.
So you're always going to enter that first if statement.

Try

```
if again == "y" or again == "Y":
```

or

```
if again.lower() == "y":
```

or

```
if again in ["y", "Y"]:
```

and the same changes for the elif